# What software and web sites are portrayed in Dexter?

Tags: dexter

I noticed while watching Dexter series that absolutely nothing that happens on a computer screen looks even remotely familiar. Operating systems are not Windows, OSX or Linux, nor are they re-skins of those, blogs look similar to LiveJournal but obviously are not a custom skin, chat programs look like nothing i have seen before. And there is a lot of detail in those, too. Usually there is always some small detail, something that lets you tell this is actually some familiar software. But in Dexter - nothing.

This have been bugging me. Is this just some actual software that i have never seen? Or did they actually take time to design all this (quite cheesy, frankly) stuff that most of the time can only be seen on the screen for a split second? And why on earth would they do that?

Comment: usually those things are invented for tv/film to avoid claims for surreptitious advertising.

Answer (score 5):

I think they actually design all or may be few of the software used in Dexter.

For example according to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_%28TV_series%29#External_links) the search engine used by Dexter can be found here: [netrangler](http://www.netrangler.com/)

Comment: The link seems to have expired, seems it's available here though: http://www.iywib.com/netrangler/netrangler/index.php. There is also eliotsearchengine.com (given to Dexter by Masukas game developer intern - Jamie?) and Finder Spyder (seems to be a running thing in different shows similar to the Howie scream)

Comment: @Dan Gamer developer intern was Louis, right? Also the link eliotsearchengine.com doesn't work anymore. But there's one search engine https://www.yelliot.com/ that comes up when I Google the phrase eliotsearchengine.